How did this zucchini plant cling to the zip tie?
I'm somewhat curious to know how this zucchini plant "saw" the zip tie and managed to get closer and tie up.

What are the biological mechanisms that allow it to do so?

"Tendril" is the terminology for the part of the plant that is clinging to the zip tie.

Note that it also "saw" the wire screen behind it, I see what looks like 3 other tendrils grasping onto that.  The zip tie was just slightly closer.

True Facts: Plants That Explode visits this topic. WARNING: Contains crude/mature humour.

Plant movement is called tropism, and for your squash it's specifically thigmotropism, movement in response to touch.  Your zuchinni didn't see the zip tie, it found it :-). Here is time lapse of a bean plant groping around.

Regarding the mechanism, Wikipedia explains it like this:

This behavior occurs due to unilateral growth inhibition. That is,
the growth rate on the side of the stem which is being touched is
slower than on the side opposite the touch. The resultant growth
pattern is to attach and sometimes curl around the object which is
touching the plant.


It didn't actually see anything.
The tendril did what tendrils do - It swung round and round (to anthropomorphize ) - blindly groping for anything to latch on to.   As soon as it "felt" something - ie the cable tie here - it started trying to twirl around, curling around whatever part made contact with it.
I did do a bit of digging around, and while there is some evidence that light seeking does play a role in tendril development and where it grows towards ( https://nph.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdfdirect/10.1111/nph.15073 ) It does not appear that even this would have played a significant role in "seeing" the zip tie.

https://www.scienceabc.com/nature/how-do-climbing-plants-know-where-to-climb.html is an interesting read.   (BTW, Zucchini are part of the curcubit family which includes squash and cucumbers as well - so things mentioning squash or cucumbers is likely at least somewhat relevant to Zucchini)

You may notice them curving around (like sunflowers) until they find something to attach (or just ignoring and try again later and upper). I think your nest is too dense, so the tendril may not see it as something to attach.
